# how can I get the unique number of clients according to date ranges?

Tags: google-sheets

how can I get the unique number of clients according to date ranges? I am trying to get the number of clients each week and I cannot find a way. Here is a sample of the data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1brErf1q5KI8ir8GFFZ48KQpm7U_lCMCsPgwmCCpcNy8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put this in `F1`:

`=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A >= $D2, $A$2:$A <= $E2))`

Comment: No worries! Make your spreadsheet public next time :) Will just make it easier to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In F2 and copied down to suit:

```
=if(iserror(FILTER($B$2:$B,$A$2:$A>=$D2,$A$2:$A<=$E2)),0,COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B,$A$2:$A>=$D2,$A$2:$A<=$E2)))
```